# Two finger scrolling not working on ASUS UX303LN

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, asus, scrolling, focaltech

I am using ASUS UX303 LN laptop, and ubuntu 14.04 Gnome is installed on it. I cant turn on two finger scrolling on it. Its not even shown in the settings. Can someone help ? I have tried these commands, but didnt work

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms
```

Output for  xinput; dmesg | grep pnp

```
ebin@Ebin-UX303LN:~$ xinput; dmesg | grep pnp
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[    0.266621] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.267063] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.267303] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs FLT0101 SYN0a00 SYN0002 PNP0f03 PNP0f13 PNP0f12 (active)
[    0.267350] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[    0.268431] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 10 devices
```

output for uname -r; dkms status

```
ebin@Ebin-UX303LN:~$ uname -r; dkms status
3.16.0-41-generic
```

Comment: These models can have different touchpads. Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `uname -r; dkms status` command.

Comment: It looks like `focaltech-dkms` is not installed. You will need to install it again after kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Focaltech touchpad and the driver from my ppa should work.

But it looks like I made a small mistake and did not add dependency of `linux-generic-lts-vivid` in the last version for trusty.

The driver did not install for your current kernel.

You need to run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot. That will upgrade your kernel and the driver will work.

I fixed that issue in ppa. Now it will force to install `linux-generic-lts-vivid` for Ubuntu 14.04.

Now version 1.5~trusty1 is building. It will be the last version in that ppa, because this driver is in kernel 4.0 and with my finger width patch in 4.2.

Focaltech touchpads will work in Ubuntu 15.10 out of the box.

Comment: So i just have to update the kernel for now ?

Comment: Just run that command and reboot. It will install kernel for Ubuntu 14.04.3. If you already installed focaltech-dkms, it should build OK automatically. If not reinstall it.

Comment: OK. Lemme try that ! I didnt know that ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms is yours  :D

Comment: More than 1000 installs from it )))

Comment: First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building for 3.16.0-41-generic and 3.19.0-21-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.16.0-41-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.16.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/focaltech/1.5~trusty/build/make.log for more information.

This is what I am getting. What to do?

Comment: It is OK. It will not build for 3.16, but will build for 3.19. It is weird that no one reported that mistake so far. It should force you to install that 3.19 to avoid confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25522/discussion-between-ebin-p-issac-and-pilot6).

Comment: I did not even have to reboot. `rmmod psmouse ; modprobe psmouse` was good enough. Thank you for your excellent work!